# MSSQL and PHP: "An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query."

Tags: php, sql-server, object, sql-update

I'm trying to run a very simple MSSQL update statement through PHP, but I get an error saying *"An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query."*

Here's the [connection class](http://pastebin.com/3j4zmHJY) I'm using, and most relevant is the query function:

```
function query($query) {
    $result = sqlsrv_query($query) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Finally, here's the code I'm using to try to execute the statement:

```
$db = new mssqlClass();
$conn = $db->connect();

$SQL = "UPDATE table SET Title = 'Test' where ID = 1"
$SQL = $db->query($SQL);
```

If anyone has any suggestions I'd be very grateful, I guess it's a problem with the connection class but I'm unsure. Thank you!

(edit) In trying to edit everything down for the purpose of posting here, I somehow missed the 'where' from my statement, agh! Sorry. Needless to say **the query is fine, and when copied into SQL Server Studio Manager executes without any issues**. Cheers

Comment: Whoops, looks like I grossly misinterpreted your previous flag. Sorry about that! I've reopened your question now. Obsolete answers are usually up to the owners to revise or remove, though, especially since you've commented on each of them, so I'm leaving them alone for now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't like answering my own questions, but since I made such a mess of asking this question initially I'm hoping this is helpful for anyone seeing this from Google.

Unlike mssql_query, the newer sqlsrv_query function needs the connection paramter to be passed in as the first variable, like so:

```
$result = sqlsrv_query($this->connection, $query) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
```

Comment: what about the prepare statements?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing the WHERE keyword. Is that suppose to say:

```
UPDATE table SET Title = 'Test' WHERE ID = 1
```

?

Comment: In trying to edit everything down for the purpose of posting here, I somehow missed the 'where' from my statement, agh! Sorry. Needless to say the query is fine, and when copied into SQL Server Studio Manager executes without any issues. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 UPDATE table SET Title = 'Test', ID = 1
```

you miss the comma ","

Comment: In trying to edit everything down for the purpose of posting here, I somehow missed the 'where' from my statement, agh! Sorry. Needless to say the query is fine, and when copied into SQL Server Studio Manager executes without any issues. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying either of this

```
UPDATE table SET Title = 'Test' WHERE ID = 1
```

OR

```
UPDATE table SET Title = 'Test', ID = 1
```

Comment: In trying to edit everything down for the purpose of posting here, I somehow missed the 'where' from my statement, agh! Sorry. Needless to say the query is fine, and when copied into SQL Server Studio Manager executes without any issues. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It is an old solution:

```
$result = sqlsrv_query($this->connection, $query) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
```

But saved me miles, two years latter on!

Comment: what about the prepare statements?